# Incorrect encoding to display characters in table

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

Words in the table are not readable. How do I use the correct encoding to display the characters? This is my code:

```
\caption{Generalized search strings for the databases}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X|}
\hline

TITLE-ABS-KEY ( "electric* load forecast*" OR  "electric* load predicti*" OR "electric* demand forecast*" OR "electric* demand predicti*" ) AND ( LIMIT TO ( PUBSTAGE ,  "final" ) ) AND ( LIMIT-TO ( SRCTYPE,"j" ) ) AND ( LIMIT-TO ( SUBJAREA ,  "ENGI" ) OR LIMIT-TO ( SUBJAREA ,  "COMP" ) OR LIMIT-TO ( SUBJAREA ,  "ENER" ) )  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab3}
\end{table}
```

The code above gives the following output:
[image: my output]

Comment: always show a small but complete example.

Comment: You have a Unicode UTF-8 no-break space `( "el...` but have declared a different encoding, possibly `latin1`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have used ```\UseRawInputEncoding```. How should i fix this then?

Comment: Never use `\UseRawInputEncoding` unless you are in very special legacy situation and really understand all latex interals. It disables _all_ latex support for non-ascii characters allowing you to define some custom code if you _really_ need non-standard behaviour. Also please always provide proper examples here, it is hard to debug code you do not show.,

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is unrelated to tables, your document has non breaking space U+00A0

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\UseRawInputEncoding 

\begin{document}

( "el..
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

The solution is simple, remove `\UseRawInputEncoding` which should never be used in normal documents, it disables LaTeX's support for non ascii characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

( "el..
\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]